# box-shadow won't display on the bottom of the div

Tags: html, css

I have a page that looks like this:

[box-shadow http://www.morninj.com/images/box-shadow-screenshot.png](http://www.morninj.com/images/box-shadow-screenshot.png)

The middle div (with "Quotation." as its contents) has a box-shadow property applied. For some reason, the shadow won't appear below the second div if the third div is present. Does anybody know why?

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div><!--/#header-->
<div id="subheader">
    <h2>"Quotation."</h2>
</div><!--/#subheader-->
<div id="blurb">
    <div id="blurb-container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div><!--/#blurb-container-->
</div><!--/#blurb-->
```

CSS:

```
div#header {
    background-color: #444;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

    div#header h1 {
        color: #fff;
        font-family: 'Arvo', sans-serif;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    }

div#subheader {
    background-color: #777;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px #333;
    padding: 10px;
}

    div#subheader h2 {
        color: #efefef;
        font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }

div#blurb {
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding: 20px;
}

    div#blurb div#blurb-container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 800px;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your 'blurb' is covering it up.  Edit the `div#blurb` css rule to the following to move it behind the shadowed div:

```
div#blurb {
    background-color: #efefef;
    padding: 20px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'd tried using z-index to no avail, but position: relative fixes it. Just curious—can you (or anybody) explain why position: relative is needed here?

Answer (score 2):

Set the position of both elements to relative and the z-index of the first one to 1 and the lower one to 0.

Edit: yes, negative values are allowed :). But they don't work in firefox 2.

Comment: Unless I'm not reading the spec correctly, negative z-indexes are allowed. [http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index)